# iis server response time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I'm currently running Google's PageSpeed tool and the one thing it keeps complaining about is the Server Response Time.

It's currently running at around 2.5s..

Specs:

16GB Ram
W2k8 R2 64Bit
Intel Xeon CPI X5560 @ 2.8Ghz

This is a virtual machine running on a machine which has apparently good specs, but i'm not sure what they are.

The server runs just IIS (SQL is located on another server, I use IP's to reference the DB rather than hostnames)..

The IIS server hosts around 15 small-ish e-commerce websites, even the homepage of one of the websites takes around 4 seconds to load, with 2.6 of those seconds waiting on the server.. on this particular website the homepage is cached using a MemoryCache (c#) so that it doesn't hit the database for each subsequent request...

Not sure what other information I should give..

How can I delve deeper into this? What else can I look at?

Comment: Are they dynamic pages?  Could that delay be caused by waiting on the server to generate the page to be served?  (Also, Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2 are completely different OSes.)

Comment: Yes, every page has some sort of dynamic content which is pulled from the database.. the homepage however is cached so there is only one query that actually runs on page load and its a tiny one field select query..

Comment: Do the app pools get idle and thus may be shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

To get some deeper insights into request processing, turn on [Failed Request Tracing](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)

To use the Failed Request Tracing feature, make sure that the following IIS Role Service is installed:

*Health and Diagnostics*: **Tracing**

[image]